# Cannot install spring-boot-starter-parent no matter what I do

Tags: java, spring, windows, maven

I just setup a new computer -- fully new Java 1.8 installation, new 3.5.2 Maven configuration, and I'm now working on setting up a fresh quickstart Maven project.

When I add the parent spring boot starter and a single dependency, it cannot resolve it no matter what I do.

Here's the trace:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.boot:das-boot:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.9-RELEASE in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 11
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.boot:das-boot:1.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\workspace\das-boot\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.boot:das-boot:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.9-RELEASE in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

And here's my full `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9-RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <name>das-boot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Output of `mvn -version`:

```
D:\workspace\das-boot>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T00:58:13-07:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

What could possibly be going on? I'm not behind a proxy, it fails in IntelliJ and on CMD, and everything is freshly installed w/ default settings.

Comment: Indeed. output added to question body

Comment: In your IDE ,Rigth button on your project -> Maven -> Update  ?

Comment: I've been running IntelliJ's "reimport" but doesn't seem to help

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125025/maven-and-spring-boot-non-resolvable-parent-pom-repo-spring-io-unknown-host

Comment: It seems like their issue is particular to grabbing a snapshot build. Since I'm grabbing a release, I shouldn't have to point to anything other than Maven Central as far as I know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `1.5.9.RELEASE`, according to [their website](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), not `1.5.9-RELEASE`.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something stupid.. Thanks so much lol.. It's always amazes me how easy it is to feel like a college freshman again when programming sometimes

Comment: I have the same code as this answer (with a 'dot' before RELEASE). But still having the same error as the question. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @RDhaval Please post a question that contains at least your pom and the error.

Comment: I solved that now, after formatting my system I had forgotten to add settings.xml file in m2. That was really silly.