# Non-resolvable parent POM and Could not transfer artifact from/to central repository and transfer failed for spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.4.pom

Tags: docker, maven, networking

My Pom File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <!--<relativePath/>--> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rakib</groupId>
    <artifactId>kube_demo_child</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kube_demo_child</name>
    <description>kube_demo_child</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Dockerfile:

```
ARG JDK=maven:3.8.2-openjdk-16-slim
ARG JRE=openjdk:16-jre-slim-buster

FROM ${JDK} AS build
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY src /home/app/src
ADD pom.xml .
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM ${JRE}
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/kube_demo_child-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/kube_demo_child-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/kube_demo_child-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

**Giving this error while i trying to build a docker image:**

[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.rakib:kube_demo_child:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/home/app/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.rakib:kube_demo_child:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.4/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.4.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Temporary failure in name resolution -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
The command '/bin/sh -c mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: This usualy means you have no internet in the container (or at least you can't reach rpo.maven.apache.org. Maybe you are behind a proxy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven and Spring Boot - non resolvable parent pom - repo.spring.io (Unknown host)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125025/maven-and-spring-boot-non-resolvable-parent-pom-repo-spring-io-unknown-host)

Comment: No sir, i am not behind on proxy...

Comment: its build successfully when i run it on ide or pc mvn....its gives error when i try to build docker image

Comment: Try to run a ping google.com in your container, you may have connectivity issue

Comment: when i can to build image....how can i ping

Comment: The problem is this: `transfer failed for` and if you are behind a proxy you have to configure to use the proxy via `settings.xml`... or maybe using an internal repository manager...

Comment: i chaecking it.....its not working.....exception occuring when i go to make a docker build....normally its maven build successfully work.